# Configuring Einstein email recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I am configuring email recommendation in personalization builder marketing cloud, and I have installed collect code(to track user views) and based on this I am expecting igo_views Data extension to auto-populate. but I am not getting the views.
am I right with this approach or i need to correct something?
Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: These data extensions populate only for identified users, did you implement user tracking? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5

Comment: And what about an anonymous user visiting my website, if i want to add him/her in my data  extension

Comment: If you want to track an anonymous user, you can generate a GUID on their first page view in place of their email address.

Answer (score 0):

Have you '[Turn On Einstein Recommendations Data Extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_enable_pb_data_extensions.htm&type=5)' if so only items that are in your catalog will populate into this DE

Comment: Yes, i have already done that

Comment: And your the item you are tracking is in the catalog?

Comment: How do i map product ids in my catalog with the ids of product in my web page??